# How to get textOutput working when using Slidy with Shiny runtime

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

The following code has satisfying results locally But when uploaded on shinyapps.io does not work.

````
---
title: "shiny slidy app"
author: "IMI"
date: "11/29/2018"
output:
  slidy_presentation:
    self_contained: yes
runtime: shiny
---

```{r data, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
library(shiny)
data<- data.frame(Year= 1990:1999)
```


## First

```{r slideselect, echo=T, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
sliderInput("year", "Year",
    min = min(data$Year), max = max(data$Year),
    value = c(min(data$Year),max(data$Year)))       

```

```{r print, echo=T}
year<-reactive(input$year)
output$rendtext<-renderText( year()[1]:year()[2])
textOutput("rendtext")
```
````

### [shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.shinyapps.io/test/):

[image]

### local:

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code and it worked well:

[image]

I made the following steps in Rstudio:

1) Create a new Rmd file

````
---
title: "shiny slidy app"
author: "IMI"
date: "11/29/2018"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  slidy_presentation:
    self_contained: yes
runtime: shiny
---

```{r data, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
library(shiny)
data<- data.frame(Year= 1990:1999)
```


## First

```{r slideselect, echo=T, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
sliderInput("year", "Year",
    min = min(data$Year), max = max(data$Year),
    value = c(min(data$Year),max(data$Year)))       

```

```{r print, echo=T}
year<-reactive(input$year)
output$rendtext<-renderText( year()[1]:year()[2])
textOutput("rendtext")
```
````

2) Publish it on shinyapp.io via the dedicated button

---

Also I tried with a basic shiny deployment (looked at the [shiny guidelines](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/sliders.html)) and with this it's ok as well: it runs both local and on shinyapp.io.

```
# Global variables can go here
library(shiny)
data <- data.frame(Year= 1990:1999)

# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  # Input: Simple integer interval ----
  sliderInput("year", "Year", min = min(data$Year), max = max(data$Year), value = c(min(data$Year),max(data$Year))),

  # Output: Text output summarizing the values ----
  textOutput("rendtext")

)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Reactive expression for the input values ---
  year <- reactive(input$year)  

  # Show the values ----
  output$rendtext<-renderText( year()[1]:year()[2])


}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: shinyapps.io]

Comment: Thank you, It was due to missing the `html_document`, but why it is working locally without `html_document` in YAML?

Comment: adding `html_document` makes output page smaller

Comment: Hi, tried the following [code](http://txt.do/1szvu) and it worked both locally and remotely (here's the [remote app link](https://abenedetti.shinyapps.io/test_md/)). Can you try it as well?

Comment: It works. I do not know why the behaviors of shiny are different.

Comment: Maybe we're using different tools versions? [Here](https://textuploader.com/1sv05) the packages versions I have.I'm on  `R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)` and `RStudio 1.1.463`.